# Creating a Task list and Assigning to preset groups

Tags: permissions, tasks, task-list

I want to set up a task list that will be used by same Organization to Task different sub organizations beneath them.  I want to have the one organization be able to choose with radio buttons who it wants to task from the choices given instead of typing in groups.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will need a choice column manually updated with group names and some javascript on the form to hide and set a Person field on choice field value change.

Comment: Problem is I don't code! Any OOTB solution you are aware of?

Comment: No, nothing OOTB that I know of.